# rake db:migrate:reset to dump schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

Hell, I'm following in Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and I'm on chapter 9 adding administrative control to users.

I'm at the part where it says

> reset the database:

```
 $ bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset
 $ bundle exec rake db:seed
```

Last time I followed this (much earlier in the tutorial), it reset the database as instructed but also deleted me schema.rb. Which was annoying.

Attempted it again, and yet again it deleted my database and erased my schema.rb. Surely this is not intended.

I'm having trouble figuring out what I should be doing anymore. I'm now getting all kinds of errors with my database. I get errors about pending migrations, but no db:xxx command works, every command just spits out this long list of errors such as

```
/Users/Ke0/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/Ke0/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/Users/Ke0/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/Users/Ke0/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/Users/Ke0/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/Users/Ke0/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/Users/Ke0/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Users/Ke0/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

What does one do in such a situation?

Comment: You sure the tutorial says "$ bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset?" "rake db:reset" is really a wrapper for "rake db:drop db:create" so why would the tutorial ask you to migrate the database to the latest schema and then drop it before recreating it again, this time without the latest schema.

Comment: That's what is says, I copy pasted the command from the PDF. Here's a link to the online version [link](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#code-fixture_users_activated) hopefully that works

Comment: I might have figured out the issue, I think it was dumping my schema.rb as an unintended side effect of having rails server running in another terminal tab. I'm also reading that db:reset drops the database and seeds with your seeds.rb if you have one, thus the second command (db:seed) isn't needed am I correct?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html). rake db:reset is a wrapper for db:drop and db:setup, while setup is a wrapper for db:create and db:seed, so yeah, the tutorial makes sense now. Reset does more than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

try to verify following :-

1. you have the db with username/password mentioned in database.yml
2. you have db empty
3. when you run `rake db:migrate`,then `schema.rb` is getting generated
4. you have a valid `database.yml` file

Comment: My database.yml doesn't have any username/password information in it. But the file itself has remain unchanged since it was created with this project.

Currently my database isn't empty

When I do run rake db:migrate a new a db is being generated with the info from schema.rb